# Sed - Use '/1' to get value of environment variable

Tags: sed, environment-variables

I have the following `sed` command:

```
sed -i -E "s/\{\{(.*)\}\}/$(echo "$\1")/g" test.conf
```

In `test.conf`, I have this:

```
this is a {{TEST}}
and this is an {{ANSWER}} here.
```

And I have the follow environment variables set:

```
export TEST=1234
export ANSWER=5678
```

When I run the `sed` command, I end up with this result:

```
this is a $TEST
and this is an $ANSWER here.
```

I want `1234` and `5678` there respectively. Is there a reason the `echo` command is interpreting things literally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backreferences are used internally by a single sed command. The echo has no idea about sed backreferences and would have been invoked by the shell before the sed command has even run so the `$(echo "$\1")` is outputing `$\1` so

```
sed -i -E "s/\{\{(.*)\}\}/$(echo "$\1")/g" test.conf
```

is really:

```
sed -i -E "s/\{\{(.*)\}\}/$\1/g" test.conf
```

hence the output you are seeing.

Anyway, sed is for simple subsitutions on individual lines, for anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ export TEST=1234 ANSWER=5678
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*)\{\{(.*)\}\}(.*)/,a){$0=a[1] ENVIRON[a[2]] a[3]} 1' file
this is a 1234
and this is an 5678 here.
```

The above uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(), with other awks it'd be:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/\{\{(.*)\}\}/){$0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) ENVIRON[substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-4)] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)} 1' file
this is a 1234
and this is an 5678 here.
```

If anyone suggests running `eval` or similar on the sed output - don't do it (google `eval is evil` and friends), just use the awk command above for simple string operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `perl` which conveniently has a `%ENV` hash variable, see [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/Env.html) for more info

```
perl -pe 's/\{\{(.*)\}\}/$ENV{$1}/' test.conf
```